# Not able to get my Form align into center

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, html, twitter-bootstrap-4

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">`
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!--custom css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="cover">
        <div id="cover-caption">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                     <h1>Welcome to Bootstrap 4.0 !</h1>
                     <p>This is the platform that was created by twitter and is used in every website today</p>

                    <form action="" class="form-inline">
                       <div class="form-group">  <label class="sr-only">Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control
form-control-lg" placeholder="Tanveer">
                       </div>


                        <div class="form-group">  <label class="sr-only">Email</label> <input type="text" class="form-control
form-control-lg" placeholder="tanveer@example.com ">
                       </div>
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit</button>
                     </form>


                </div>

              </div>


            </div>

          </section>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-full"
id="nav-main">   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 4.0</a> 
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>   </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>   </div> </nav>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js""></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should be tagged with javascript not java

Answer (score 0):

One vary basic and simple way to change a html tag to be in the center is to use align attribute:

```
<form align="center">
 This sentence will be in the center!
</div>
```

Please try and change this code:

```
      <form action="" class="form-inline" >
            <div class="form-group">  <label class="sr-only">Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Tanveer">
            <div class="form-group">  <label class="sr-only">Email</label> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="tanveer@example.com "> Submit
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

To:

```
        <form action="" class="form-inline" align="center">
            <div class="form-group">  <label class="sr-only">Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Tanveer">
            <div class="form-group">  <label class="sr-only">Email</label> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="tanveer@example.com "> Submit
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Another way is to add the  `"text-align: center;"` in your CSS file.

Comment: i used your code but it still is same and thanks for help

Comment: Strange in my computer id does work. did nothing changed? after copying my code you should see the name and div tag in the center.  maybe  post your other files (CSS and bootstrap), it can help because that way we could recreate your whole code.

Comment: @TanveerAhmad You sure the problem was not your Cache?

Answer (score -1):

You can use below CSS to align form in the center with content.

```
form {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
}
```